# Can saltstack's peer communication channel be used to run salt-cloud commands?

Tags: salt-stack

Can [saltstack's](http://docs.saltstack.com/) [peer communication](http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/peer.html#peer-communication) channel be used to run [salt-cloud](https://salt-cloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) commands?

I see there is a peer_run option

> Configuration to allow minions to execute runners from the master is
>   done via the peer_run option on the master. The peer_run configuration
>   follows the same logic as the peer option. The only difference is that
>   access is granted to runner modules.

Runners are described as

> Salt runners are convenience applications executed with the salt-run
>   command.
>
> Salt runners work similar to salt modules however they execute on the
>   Salt master itself instead of each individual Salt minion.
>
> A Salt runner can be a simple client call, or a complex application.
>
> The use for a Salt runner is to build a frontend hook for running sets
>   of commands via Salt or creating special formatted output.

So it struck me that salt-cloud might be one of the applications I could run.  However the [list](http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/runners/all/index.html#all-salt-runners) of existing salt-runners doesn't seemed to include salt-cloud.  Am I missing anything or is there an easy way to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A runner is really just a python file that is executed on the Salt Master. You could definitely do Salt Cloud actions from a runner. I've built some custom runners that use Salt Cloud.